# Paging using in WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

First Create the Stored Procedure in Paging Control.Again WCF called on the Stored Procedure in Paging controls.finally WCF service are enabled in the WPF application using in Paging Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Paging controls are used in the WCF application with include on the Stored procedure.This application can be executed in successfully.i have test on more time.

enter code here:Sevicesname:IEmployeeServices.cs

{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        #region Properties
        [OperationContract]
        string AddEmployeeDetails(Employee Employee);

```
    [OperationContract]
    List<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails(int PageNumber,int PageSize,string SortColumn,string SortOrder);

    [OperationContract]
    string UpdateEmployeeDetails(Employee Employee);
    #endregion
}
```

}

```
enter code here:EmployeeServices.svc
```

namespace EmployeeServiceApps
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        #region Methods
        /// 
        /// Add the New EmployeeRecord Methods
        /// 
        /// 
        /// 
        public string AddEmployeeDetails(Employee Employee)

```
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        try
        {
            string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Employee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Employee.EmployeeID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", Employee.EmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeAddress", Employee.EmployeeAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeePhoneNo", Employee.EmployeePhoneNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Employee.Action);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            result = "Record Inserted Successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update EmployeeRecords Methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Employee"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string UpdateEmployeeDetails(Employee Employee)
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds;
        ds = new DataSet();
        string result = string.Empty;
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Employee", con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeID", Employee.EmployeeID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeName", Employee.EmployeeName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeeAddress", Employee.EmployeeAddress);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmployeePhoneNo", Employee.EmployeePhoneNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", Employee.Action);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = "Record Updated Sucessfully";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// GetEmployeeDetails Methods
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Employee> GetEmployeeDetails(int PageNumber, int PageSize, string SortColumn, string SortOrder)
    {
        List<Employee> Employees = null;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        DataSet ds;
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        ds = new DataSet();
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Employee", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "GET");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageNumber", PageNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", PageSize);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortColumn", SortColumn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortOrder", SortOrder);
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(ds);
            sda.Dispose();
            Employees = parseEmployeeDetails(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return Employees;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///Parsing the EmployeeRecords
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dsEmployeeDetails"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Employee> parseEmployeeDetails(DataSet dsEmployeeDetails)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = null;
        try
        {
            employees = new List<Employee>();

            if (dsEmployeeDetails != null && dsEmployeeDetails.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt = dsEmployeeDetails.Tables[0];

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Employee employee = new Employee();

                    employee.EmployeeID = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeID"]);
                    employee.EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeName"]);
                    employee.EmployeeAddress = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeeAddress"]);
                    employee.EmployeePhoneNo = Convert.ToString(dr["EmployeePhoneNo"]);
                    employee.TotalCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TotalCount"]);
                    employees.Add(employee);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return employees;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}